# Why are matrix operations Using the CRC or CRS format for sparse matric faster than using the LIL format in scipy?

Tags: algorithm, scipy, sparse-matrix

I know that in scipy, it is good practice to construct your graph in the LIL format then convert said graph in the CRS or CRS format when you want to do operations on this matrix.

however I don't see how it could increase performances when using CRS/CRC format over the LIL format as the time to access data is the same in both cases, or is there something I am missing ?

===

```
$\sum_{n} F^n(v)$
```

with

```
F(v) := $\bigvee_{j \in V} M_{i, j} \wedge v^n_j$
```

and `M` the adjacency matrix, `v` a vector (usually `e_i`).

third, the sparsity of the `F^n(v)` vectors would be between `10^(-5)` and `10^(-3)`.

Comment: You've misread the `lil` docs.  It's say that if you need to create the matrix iteratively, setting elements individually or in groups, the `lil` format is more efficient than the `csr`.  The original, and still best way of constructing a matrix is to use the `coo` style of inputs - 3 arrays of data, row and col indices.  Alternatively the `csr` `indptr` can be used, but that's harder to understand.  In any case, most calculations are done in the `csr` format, especially matrix multiplication.

Comment: Also to clarify - it is not good practice to construct your graph in `lil` format. The memory overhead of multiple python objects for every nonzero point is extraordinary. It is a format that you should use as an absolute last resort, when you intend to continually change the sparsity and have no way of doing a two-pass approach where you determine the number of nonzero values ahead of time. In almost all cases, if you have arrived at a point where a `lil` matrix makes any sense, you have made serious mistakes in your design.

Comment: I am using a sparse matrix to represent a dependency graph, or directed acyclic graph.
the issue i have is that this graph can be and will be modified at runtime so having the lil format is a must here.

also almost all of the operations i make are matrix vector operations with the vector being e_i so it can be computed using a simple get from the list in the lil format.
my question was in the case of matrix vector product (in the case where the vector isn't e_i), why is the LIL format slower and by how much ?

Comment: It is not possible to do any math using the `LIL` format. Period. The elements of a list are not memory-contiguous, a list is not a vector. Every math operation will require an implicit conversion to a `CSR` matrix, which is actually more expensive than changing the sparsity of an existing `CSR` matrix (which is very expensive). I would carefully benchmark what you plan to do as the best choices depend on exactly what your algorithm is.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my comment. I am not doing matrix operations, i am only doing memory accesses so no matrix vectors operations are done here. my question was to see if there could be a potential speed up to one of my algorithm if i used a CSR matrix instead of a LIL one.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear you have an XY problem here, so maybe it would be better to ask about what you're actually doing. I will reiterate `The elements of a list are not memory-contiguous, a list is not a vector`.

Comment: Actually, I'll rephrase what i said. 

first of all, i am not really using a LIL format matrix but its equivalent in graph theory which is the adjacency list. 

secondly, the operation i am doing is the following:
$\sum_{n} F^n(v)$ with F(v) :=
 $\bigvee_{j \in V} M_{i, j} \wedge v^n_j$ and M the adjacency matrix, v a vector (usually e_i).

third, the sparsity of the F^n(v) vectors would be between 10^(-5) and 10^(-3).

Comment: The only operation I am doing right now is the equivalent of F(e_i) as defined earlier, but this is equivalent to looking at all the elements inside the list of a LIL matrix for a given vertex. given that we are using a hashmap and the elements inside the list (also a hashmap) are actually a reference to the objects we are using, this is actually a great algorithmic speed up to get the reference to the object I need.

Comment: Basically, i need to find an algorithm to find all the nodes connected to a sink node. however the complexity is in O(m) with m the number of edges inside this induced subgraph. however i would like to know if there can be an algorithm with a lower complexity using linear algebra.

Comment: The math in your comment is unreadable.  That needs to be in the question itself.  Also your question is buried under newer ones, so is unlikely to be seen by some following your tags.  I only saw your later comments because I was checking back on sparse questions I'd commented on before.  To learn more how sparse formats work look at how elements are stored, such as the `data` attribute.

Comment: yeah i have seen now why this question was so hard to answer as i assumed wrongly how the LIL format was implemented in the scipy library. I am actually reformulating my question so as that no one misunderstand what i was trying to ask. also, unless SO allows for math formula inside the comments, i don't see other ways to show a math formula without editing the original text.

Comment: actually I think I will delete this question and create a new post as the question is not really relevant and stems from my misunderstanding from misreading the documentation of scipy. i'll let this open for the week in case you'd think i should keep it, otherwise it will be deleted.

Comment: `lil` has two object dtype arrays, each containing lists, one per row.  Object dtype is much like a list, hence the name 'lists in lists'.  Selecting a row of such matrix is easy, or even a subset of rows (see code for `getrow` or `getrowview`); column access goes via the base function and `csc` format.  More details can be found in the scipy/scipy/sparse/_lil.py file.